# What does colon mean in ANT srcdir value eg.<javac:srcdir="${ejb-source-ABC}:${ejb-source}"

Tags: java, apache, ant

I am doing some analysis of the existing antscript to convert it to the maven. I observed the ":"(colon) in srcdir value of the ANT task - javac. 
Can someone please explain me what does it mean ?

eg.

```html
eg.<javac:srcdir="${ejb-source-ABC}:${ejb-source}"
```

Comment: Probably a typo. Ant files are ostensibly XML, so that would be a srcdir element with the namespace prefix javac. Instead, srcdir should be an attribute of the javac element. Does this build work? I'd expect that the colon would need to be replaced with a space.

Comment: Yes. It's an existing file and working on production

Comment: This is not valid XML. Are you sure you copied the code snippet properly?

Comment: @CAustin : I couldn't copy full xml tag as it was throwing some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `srcdir` attribute is a path, despite the attribute name suggesting otherwise.  What you’re seeing is two directories with a path separator (`:` or `;`, Ant allows either, regardless of current platform) between them.

From [documentation for Ant’s javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), in the “Parameters specified as nested elements” section:

> `<javac>'s` `srcdir` [et al.] … attributes are path-like structures …